# Swift memory leak in dictionary

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, instruments

I develop an iOS app with Swift. (Xcode 8.1, Swift 3)
I use Instruments to check my app for leaks.
I noticed that when a class holds a reference to a dictionary, so when I fill the dictionary in some function, the Instruments shows a leak. Example:

```
class A { 
 var dic : [String : Int] = [:]

    func f(array: [String]){
      for str in array {
          dic[str] = 5
      }
     }
}
```

Why this code create a leak?
Two things I noticed:

1. If the dictionary is a local var in a function so it won't create leak
2. If i replace str with a constant "some_const" - it won't create leak.

I thought it's related if the type is optional, but I tried to change it and still didn't work.

Update:

I now realized its happens only in iOS 10, and it's not just the dictionary, there are a lot weird swift-lib leaks that not appear in iOS 9.
Also, the memory usage of the app is not increasing dramatically as you except because of those leaks.

Anyone know about iOS 10 changes that may cause those leak? it's a bug maybe?

Comment: This example doesn't contain a leak, I don't think. Does your real example involve an array of `A` objects, which are added as keys to `dic`?

Comment: The real example no, but its the same concept. instead of String, i have a CoreData object with a string property.. so it will be [Category.ID] = i

Comment: I am getting memory leaks also: `Xcode 8`, `iOS 10 Simulator`. The leaks come from `CoreFoundation`, `CFNetwork`, `libswiftCore.dylib`, and `Foundation`.